# Select data from Gridview where there is multiple pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

In my gridview I have multiple pages.
I can select one or more items from Page 1 and save it in sql database.
However, If I select **one item from Page 1** and **another item from Page 2**, system only save **item from Page 1**.

aspx.cs

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
if (Session["UserName"].ToString() != null)
{
    SUserName.Text = Session["UserName"].ToString();
    SUserEmail.Text = Session["Email"].ToString();
}
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
{
    LoadUserSubSection();
    CurrentDate();
    this.SearchItems();
}
}


protected void RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
    e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "MouseEvents(this, event)");
    e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseout", "MouseEvents(this, event)");
}
 //added in               
 GridViewRow gvr = e.Row;
if (gvr.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
 {
    CheckBox chkSelect = gvr.FindControl("chkSelect") as CheckBox;

    if (chkSelect != null)
    {
        int StID = Convert.ToInt32(gvItemDesc.DataKeys[gvr.RowIndex]["StID"]);

        chkSelect.Checked = this.StItemDescIDs.Contains(StID);
       }
     }
   }
  private void SearchItems()
 {
  using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
  {
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
    {
        string sql = "SELECT [StID],[StNo],[StItemDesc],[CreatedBy] FROM [StationeryRequest]. 
          [dbo].[tblStationeryItemlist]";
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtSearch.Text.Trim()))
        {
            sql += " WHERE StItemDesc LIKE @StItemDesc + '%'";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StItemDesc", txtSearch.Text.Trim());
        }
        cmd.CommandText = sql;
        cmd.Connection = con;
        using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dt);
            gvItemDesc.DataSource = dt;
            gvItemDesc.DataBind();
          }
        }
      }
    }

   private List<int> StItemDescIDs
    {
     get
     {
    if (this.ViewState["StItemDescIDs"] == null)
       {
        this.ViewState["StItemDescIDs"] = new List<int>();
       }

        return this.ViewState["StItemDescIDs"] as List<int>;
         }
       }

   protected void SelectDeselect(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
    {
       foreach (GridViewRow gvr in gvItemDesc.Rows)
     {
         CheckBox chkSelect = gvr.FindControl("chkSelect") as CheckBox;

         if (chkSelect != null)
        {
          chkSelect.Checked = e.CommandName.Equals("SelectAll");
       }
      }
    }

    protected void OnPaging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
 //added in
    foreach (GridViewRow gvr in gvItemDesc.Rows)
    {
      CheckBox chkSelect = gvr.FindControl("chkSelect") as CheckBox;

    if (chkSelect != null)
    {
        int StID = Convert.ToInt32(gvItemDesc.DataKeys[gvr.RowIndex]["StID"]);

        if (chkSelect.Checked && !this.StItemDescIDs.Contains(StID))
        {
            this.StItemDescIDs.Add(StID);
        }
        else if (!chkSelect.Checked && this.StItemDescIDs.Contains(StID))
           {
            this.StItemDescIDs.Remove(StID);
           }
         }
       }    
         gvItemDesc.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
       this.SearchItems();
      }

      protected void Search(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
       this.SearchItems();
     }
```

submit btn

```
       protected void btnSubmit(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            object id;
           //insert into Main Parent table -> tblStationeryRequest
           string insertCmdtblStationeryRequest = "INSERT INTO tblStationeryRequest 
           (Department,RequestFor,UserName,Date,Email,Status) " +
          "output inserted.StReqID " + //Get auto increment for StReqID
         "VALUES (@Department,@RequestFor,@UserName,@Email,@Date,@Status)";
         string Status = "Pending";

    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(cs))
    {
    conn.Open();
    using (SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand(insertCmdtblStationeryRequest, conn))
    {
        sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Department", ddlDept.SelectedItem.Text);
        sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RequestFor", ddlName.SelectedItem.Text);
        sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", lblCurrentDate.Text);
        sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", SUserName.Text);
        sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", SUserEmail.Text);

        sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Status", Status);
        //get id from auto increment and will be used it in Child tables -> tblItemRequest, 
          tblSupplierRequest and so on.
        //sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        id = sqlcmd.ExecuteScalar(); //the result is of Object type, cast it safely
      }
   }

     Debug.WriteLine(id.ToString()); // Access it like this

  string lblStID = "";

  foreach (GridViewRow row in gvItemDesc.Rows)
   {
    CheckBox status = (row.Cells[1].FindControl("chkSelect") as CheckBox);
    if (status.Checked)
    {
        if (lblStID != "")
        {
            lblStID += ",";
        }
        lblStID += (row.Cells[1].FindControl("chkSelect") as CheckBox).Text;

       }

   }
//In Page 1, can select one or more items 
//However Page 1 one item and Page 2 one time, it only save from Page 1

     string insertCmdtblRequestItemListID = "INSERT INTO tblRequestItemListID(StReqID, StID, 
     StItemDesc) select " + id.ToString() + ",StID,StItemDesc from tblStationeryItemlist where 
    StID in (" + lblStID + ")";

      using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(cs))
    {
    conn.Open();
    using (SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand(insertCmdtblRequestItemListID, conn))
        sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
      }
```

.aspx

Here is my Gridview

```
       < asp:GridView ID = "gvItemDesc" runat = "server" AutoGenerateColumns = "false" 
         AllowPaging = "true" DataKeyNames = "StID" OnPageIndexChanging = "OnPaging" 
         OnRowDataBound = "RowDataBound" Font - Size = "11pt" >
       < Columns >
       < asp:TemplateField >
       < HeaderTemplate >
                        //no need use Check all function
       < asp:CheckBox ID = "checkAll" runat = "server" Text = '<%#Eval("StID") %>' onclick 
        ="checkAll(this);" />
       </ HeaderTemplate >
       < ItemTemplate >
       < asp:CheckBox ID = "chkSelect" runat = "server" Text ='<%# Eval("StID") %>' onclick = 
         "Check_Click(this)" />
       </ ItemTemplate >
       </ asp:TemplateField >
        < asp:BoundField DataField = "StID" HeaderText = "StID" ItemStyle - Width = "150" 
         SortExpression = "StID" Visible = "false" />  

       < asp:BoundField DataField = "StItemDesc" HeaderText = "Item Description" ItemStyle - 
         Width = "150" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText = "" >
        </ asp:TemplateField >
        < asp:TemplateField HeaderText = "" >
        < ItemTemplate >
        < asp:Label ID ="lblStItemDesc" runat = "server" Text = '<%# Eval("StItemDesc") %>' 
         Visible ="false" > </ asp:Label >
           </ ItemTemplate >
          </ asp:TemplateField >
           </ Columns >
             </ asp:GridView >
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you have two approaches here.

First up, you can just during navigation, or filter, or paging have the user select data, and UPDATE the database (unless that's what you really want???).

What you want:

User can select any old row on the page. Maybe page around for fun, select a few more rows.

At that point, you THEN can process the rows selected and UPDATE the actual database.

So, we want to "separate" these two concepts to be crystal clear in your mind.

Next up:

We have two practical choices. We suffer a post back for the check box in the grid. I often use this, and it not all that bad.

If you REALLY want to avoid that post back, then on both paging event, and your final submit button, you have to "manage" that checked list.

Lets go with Mr. Easy. And if you really need the 2nd approach, then I can post a solution, but no need to do extra work when/if you don't need as such.

So, our simple grid - NOTE how the check box is un-bound - no data source.

So, our grid:

```
   <asp:GridView ID="GVHotels" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
            DataKeyNames="ID" CssClass="table" AllowPaging="true" 
            OnPageIndexChanging="GVHotels_PageIndexChanging" OnRowDataBound="GVHotels_RowDataBound">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName"   HeaderText="FirstName" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName"    HeaderText="LastName"  />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="City"        HeaderText="City" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="HotelName"   HeaderText="HotelName"  />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description"  />

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="To Process" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSel" runat="server" CssClass="bigcheck"
                         OnCheckedChanged="chkSel_CheckedChanged"
                         AutoPostBack="true" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
            <PagerStyle CssClass="GridPager" />
        </asp:GridView>
            <asp:Button ID="cmdProcess" runat="server" Text="Process selected" CssClass="btn" OnClick="cmdProcess_Click"  />
            <br />
```

Code to fill grid:

```
    List<int> MySelList = new List<int>();
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            LoadGrid();
            ViewState["MySelect"] = MySelList;
        }
        else
            MySelList = (List<int>)ViewState["MySelect"];
    }

    void LoadGrid()
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4))
        {
            string strSQL = "SELECT * FROM tblHotels " + 
                            "WHERE Description is not null " +
                            "ORDER BY HotelName";

            using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand(strSQL, conn))
            {
                conn.Open();
                DataTable rst = new DataTable();
                rst.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader());
                GVHotels.DataSource = rst;
                GVHotels.DataBind();
            }
        }
    }
```

and we now have this:

[image]

Ok, so now we need two extra routines.

The code to add/remove the selected check from the list (that we persisted).

That check box has auto post-back = true, and thus the code for that check box is this simple stub:

```
   protected void chkSel_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)sender;
        GridViewRow gRow = (GridViewRow)chk.Parent.Parent;
        int pkID = (int)GVHotels.DataKeys[gRow.RowIndex]["ID"];

        if (chk.Checked)
        {
            // add to sel list
            if (!MySelList.Contains(pkID))
               MySelList.Add(pkID);
        }
        else
            MySelList.Remove(pkID);
    }
```

Ok, that will manage the selected check boxes for us.

Now, we also need to update the display (show which rows selected).

```
    protected void GVHotels_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)e.Row.FindControl("chkSel");
            int pkID = (int)GVHotels.DataKeys[e.Row.RowIndex]["ID"];
            chk.Checked = MySelList.Contains(pkID);
        }
    }
```

Ok, we are quite much done. The user is now free to page around - select any row they want for processing. And this trick works REALLY great for some types of reports or what not. You can present grid - let user pick/choose, and then say use that result for a filter for a report, a graph, or whatever.

So, now, when the user hits that above "process" button (could be for anything).

Let's update the Hotels "Active" column = true for the ones the user selected.

Our code for the "process" button thus could be this:

```
    protected void cmdProcess_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (MySelList.Count >0)
        {
            string sWhere = " ID in (" + string.Join(",", MySelList) + ")";

            string strSQL = "UPDATE tblHotels SET Active = 1 WHERE "  + sWhere;

            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4))
            using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand(strSQL))
            {
                conn.Open();
                cmdSQL.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            // Clear our select list
            MySelList = new List<int>();
        }
    }
```

So, the above is nice, since we don't have to update the data base for this selecting process, and OFTEN that's not our goal anyway. However, as above shows, it rather easy to apply the list to some code to update the database.

Also NOTE VERY careful that I do not show, nor display the database PK id in that GV. I don't have to, since we have the DataKeys feature for that purpose. And VERY nice is that DataKeys is 100% automatic managed server side, and the key list is NOT exposed in the client side browser as plain text. (so, MUCH better for security). And since those datakeys are not based on user input - then I was able to use a simple string concatenation for the criteria. Had I used input, or even a exposed column from the GV, then we would open up to sql injection issues - but none exist in above, since we not using any displayed column from the GV.

As noted, if you REALLY can't have a post back, then we can move this code to the final submit button, but ALSO will have code in the pager event. However, I think since post-backs occur when the user has to page around then it not all that big of a deal to have a post-back for each check box event. As noted, you can always put JUST the grid in a update panel, but even then in most cases you find the above works just fine.

On the other hand, if you really WANT the data to be updated as you move aroud? then we can dump the MySel list code, and simply bind the check box to the database row. Then on paging we can update the database. The problem then becomes what happens if the user selects some rows/check box, and DOES NOT page? In other words, we almost for sure have a final button below the grid to continue? Right? So, we can update on paging, but you have to figure out what occures if they select, and don't page? And if there is some final button to hit, then again we back to my above working example anyway.